# Updating Dash Cytoscape graph with callback breaks the graph (MRE works?)

Tags: python, plotly-dash, cytoscape

**What I'm trying to do:**
I want to have an interactive graph, where I can click on a parent node, and the parent should 'collapse' (not show it's children anymore) or 'expand' (show it's children). This also means that the graph should replace the edges of it's children with edges to the parent.

As I'm still learning to use Dash-Cytoscape, I'm using a toy example. Each of the two graphs (with children and with children hidden) are separate variables. In my real project, I would dynamically re-generate the `elements` for the graph.

I can manage to write a callback function that happily feeds the graph a new set of `elements` when I click the right node (the special 'parent' nodes).

Note here, that I have both of the two example states showing what I want.

When I click the parent node, the `elements` should be replaced with the other state, making the graph show/hide the children of the parent.

See also the two states here:

[intended state with children visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Z2A.png)

[intended state with children hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjp0q.png)

**What is going wrong:**
What is instead happening is that the parent node is detached from the other nodes, it loses the edges connecting it to the rest of the graph.

See also the two *broken* states here:

[broken state with children visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHZmk.png)

[broken state with children hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqa2Z.png)

**What I tried:**
So far, I loaded each of the states separately, this shows exactly what I want
I tried to make an MRE with fewer nodes and edges, but when I run that, there is no problem. I cannot see how my MRE differs from the 'real' code where it matters.

So to be clear: What I want is to be able to switch between the two top images, but this ends up breaking the network in some way I don't understand. If you want to see the other working graph in the main code, replace `current_state = m_start_elements` with `current_state = start_elements`.

For reference, here's my MRE:

```
import dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

import threading

n1 = {'data': {'id': 'n1', 
               'label': 'n1',
               'parent': 'p1'}}
n2 = {'data': {'id': 'n2', 
               'label': 'n2',
               'parent': 'p1'}}
n3 = {'data': {'id': 'n3', 
               'label': 'n3'}}

p1 = {'data': {'id': 'p1', 
               'label': 'p1'},
      'classes': 'parent_class'}
p2 = {'data': {'id': 'p2', 
               'label': 'p2'},
      'classes': 'parent_class'}

e1 = {'data': {'id': 'e1',
               'source': 'n1', 
               'target': 'n2', 
               'label': 'e1'}}
e2 = {'data': {'id': 'e2',
               'source': 'n2', 
               'target': 'n3', 
               'label': 'e2'}}

e3 = {'data': {'id': 'e3',
               'source': 'p2', 
               'target': 'n3', 
               'label': 'e3'}}

first_elems = [n1, n2, n3, p1, e1, e2]
other_elems = [n3, p2, e3]
current_state = first_elems

parent_names = ['p1', 'p2']


layout={'name': 'grid'}

stylesheet = [
    # Group selectors
    {'selector': 'node',
     'style': {'shape': 'round-rectangle',
               'content': 'data(label)'}},
    
    {'selector': 'edge',
     'style': {'content': 'data(label)',
               'curve-style': 'unbundled-bezier',
               'width': 1,
               'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'}},

    # Class selectors
    {'selector': '.parent_class',
     'style': {'background-color': 'lightgreen',
               'border-color': 'black'}}]

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id='test-cyto',
        layout=layout,
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': '600px'},
        stylesheet=stylesheet,
        elements=current_state,
        autounselectify=True
    )
])


@app.callback(Output('test-cyto', 'elements'),
              Input('test-cyto', 'tapNodeData'),
              State('test-cyto', 'elements'))
def actionTapNodeData(tap_data, elements):

    if tap_data == None:
        # no node was clicked
        current_state = elements
    elif tap_data['id'] not in parent_names:
        # no module was clicked
        current_state = elements
    else:
        # a module was clicked
        if elements == first_elems:
            current_state = other_elems
        else:
            current_state = first_elems
    
    return current_state


def run_dash():
    app.run_server(debug=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    server = threading.Thread(target=run_dash, daemon=True)
    server.start()
```

And here's my actual code:

```
import dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

import threading
from math import pi

cyto.load_extra_layouts()


P1 = {'data': {'id': 'p1', 
               'label': 'Use Bulb'},
      'grabbable': False,
      'classes': 'process'}
P2 = {'data': {'id': 'p2', 
                'label': 'Prod. Bulb'}, 
      'grabbable': False,
      'classes': 'process'}
P3 = {'data': {'id': 'p3', 
               'label': 'Prod. Elec',
               'parent': 'm1'}, 
      'grabbable': False,
      'classes': 'process'}
P4 = {'data': {'id': 'p4', 
               'label': 'Incineration'}, 
      'grabbable': False,
      'classes': 'process'}
P5 = {'data': {'id': 'p5', 
               'label': 'Prod. Glass'}, 
      'grabbable': False,
      'classes': 'process'}
P6 = {'data': {'id': 'p6', 
               'label': 'Prod. Copper'}, 
      'grabbable': False,
      'classes': 'process'}
P7 = {'data': {'id': 'p7', 
               'label': 'Prod. Fuel',
               'parent': 'm1'}, 
      'grabbable': False,
      'classes': 'process'}

nodes = [P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7]
part_of_nodes = [P1, P2, P4, P5, P6]

E1 = {'data': {'id': 'e1',
               'source': 'p7', 
               'target': 'p3', 
               'label': 'Fuel'}}
E2 = {'data': {'id': 'e2',
               'source': 'p3', 
               'target': 'p6', 
                'label': 'Elec.'}}
E3 = {'data': {'id': 'e3',
               'source': 'p3', 
               'target': 'p2', 
               'label': 'Elec.'}}
E4 = {'data': {'id': 'e4',
               'source': 'p3', 
               'target': 'p5', 
               'label': 'Elec.'}}
E5 = {'data': {'id': 'e5',
               'source': 'p3', 
               'target': 'p1', 
               'label': 'Elec.'}}
E6 = {'data': {'id': 'e6',
               'source': 'p6', 
               'target': 'p2', 
               'label': 'Copper'}}
E7 = {'data': {'id': 'e7',
               'source': 'p5', 
               'target': 'p2', 
               'label': 'Glass'}}
E8 = {'data': {'id': 'e8',
               'source': 'p2', 
               'target': 'p1', 
               'label': 'Bulb'}}
E9 = {'data': {'id': 'e9',
               'source': 'p4', 
               'target': 'p1', 
               'label': 'Waste Treatment'}}

E22 = {'data': {'id': 'e2',
                'source': 'm2', 
                'target': 'p6', 
                'label': 'Elec.'}}
E33 = {'data': {'id': 'e3',
                'source': 'm2', 
                'target': 'p2', 
                'label': 'Elec.'}}
E44 = {'data': {'id': 'e4',
                'source': 'm2', 
                'target': 'p5', 
                'label': 'Elec.'}}
E55 = {'data': {'id': 'e5',
                'source': 'm2', 
                'target': 'p1', 
                'label': 'Elec.'}}

edges = [E1, E2, E3, E4, E5, E6, E7, E8, E9]
part_of_edges = [E22, E33, E44, E55, E6, E7, E8, E9]

M1 = {'data': {'id': 'm1', 
                'label': 'Electricity prod'}, 
      'grabbable': False,
      'classes': 'module'}

M2 = {'data': {'id': 'm2', 
                'label': 'Electricity prod'}, 
      'grabbable': False,
      'classes': 'empty_mod'}


parents = [M1]
parent_names = [n['data']['id'] for n in parents + [M2]]

start_elements = nodes + parents + edges
m_start_elements = part_of_nodes + [M2] + part_of_edges
current_state = m_start_elements

layout={'name': 'dagre',
        'spacingFactor': 1.15}

# for more info on style: https://js.cytoscape.org/#style
#TODO maange to add location label in different color
stylesheet = [
    # Group selectors
    {'selector': 'node',
     'style': {'content': 'data(label)',
               'font-size': 8}},
    
    {'selector': 'edge',
     'style': {'content': 'data(label)',
               'curve-style': 'unbundled-bezier',
               'width': 1,
               'line-color': 'lightblue',
               'target-arrow-color': 'lightblue',
               'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
               'text-margin-x': 0,
               'font-size': 8}},

    # Class selectors
    {'selector': '.process',
     'style': {'shape': 'round-rectangle',
               'background-color': 'white',
               'border-color': 'black',
               'border-width': 1,
               'text-valign': 'center',
               'height': 40,
               'width': 75}},
    {'selector': '.module',
     'style': {'shape': 'rectangle',
               'background-color': 'lightgrey',
               'border-color': 'black',
               'border-width': 1,
               'text-valign': 'center',
               'text-halign': 'left',
               'text-margin-x': -2,
               'text-rotation': (pi*2*0.75)}},
    {'selector': '.empty_mod',
     'style': {'shape': 'rectangle',
               'background-color': 'lightgrey',
               'border-color': 'black',
               'border-width': 1,
               'text-valign': 'center',
               'height': 40,
               'width': 75}}]

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id='test-cyto',
        # dagre layout: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre
        layout=layout,
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': '600px'},
        stylesheet=stylesheet,
        elements=current_state,
        autounselectify=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='hidden-div', style={'display':'none'})
])


# interaction from: https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape/events#simple-callback-construction
@app.callback(Output('test-cyto', 'elements'),
              Input('test-cyto', 'tapNodeData'),
              State('test-cyto', 'elements'))
def actionTapNodeData(tap_data, elements):

    if tap_data == None:
        # no node was clicked
        current_state = elements
    elif tap_data['id'] not in parent_names:
        # no module was clicked
        current_state = elements
    else:
        # a module was clicked
        if elements == start_elements:
            current_state = m_start_elements
        else:
            current_state = start_elements
    
    return current_state


def run_dash():
    app.run_server(debug=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    server = threading.Thread(target=run_dash, daemon=True)
    server.start()
```

Minor update: I did some further digging and it seems there are some bugs [with the Dagre implementation](https://github.com/plotly/dash-cytoscape/issues/112) when using compound nodes. I've tried using my code with the `grid` layout, but the problem persists. So this is not the problem I'm facing.